# Cannot create a coherent path with breadcrumbs

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have a menu system that goes from

Home > Song > Song_title

I have a menu item for 'Song' that is on the menu module; when I click song it brings up a list of all items with the 'popular' tag.

If I click the specific song (song_title), then on the song_title page I have a  breadcrumb which shows the same path as above.

The problem is the 'Song' menu item is different from the 'Song' in the breadcrumb, they bring up different things. The breadcrumb link brings up the ID+category link which I don't want.

Comment: Can we see your site? Do you use some extension for organizing songs or they are inside articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your breadcrumbs reflect the **content structure** of your site. It sounds like your articles (songs) are in a category called 'Song' so your breadcrumbs reflect that content hierarchy, not the menu structure.

Joomla *has to do this* because your songs are not children (in the menu structure) of the menu item 'Song', so Joomla shows the category parent in the breadcrumb instead. It *is a coherent path*, it's just not the one you want.

You should be able to fix this by creating a menu item, for each song, that is a child of the 'Song' menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Song menu item must be a Category Blog or a Category List, otherwise it won't go back to the article you come from..